# Display navigation menu list alphabetically with jquery

Tags: wordpress, list, sorting, menu, alphabetical

I am hoping some smart folks can help me here. I'm out of my depth. I had a wordpress site developed for me a little while ago. I paid the developer for his work, but he never delivered what he promised so I am left to try and fix it. Anyway...

The site uses some jquery to activate a drop down menu. When you click on a link called "Projects" it displays a slide out menu containing a list of posts. This menu contains 6 columns of text, and displays the posts in chronological order.

**There are two things I need to achieve:**
1. I need this menu to list the posts alphabetically and not chronologically.
2. I need the list order to go from top to bottom, starting from the 1st column, and continuing top to bottom in the other 5 columns. Currently it goes horizontally, so even if it was alphabetical, it would be the wrong order.

The code the currently drives the menu is below (I think). Does anyone know how I can change this so it applies the alphabetical sorting when it loads? I really don't know where to start and would be so grateful for any assistance.

```
function RegisterMenus() {        
    register_nav_menu('primary-menu', __( 'Primary Menu' ));
}
```

This page on the Wordpress site appears to have some more info about how to ad further customisation to the code:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Post your site URL so that everyone can see what jQuery is used; you might also need to post more code from the menu system.

Comment: Sorry it's all setup and installed on a secure server :( I can't get around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This JavaScript isn't sorting the menu. The menu's order is probably defined on an administration page in WordPress, which is also where you should try editing it (no coding should be required). I'm not sure about the list order direction, that *might* have to do with either JavaScript or CSS - but it could also be a setting or a piece of code in WordPress. Anyway, the code snippet you gave us is innocent.

Comment: Ok it looks like this is the wrong piece of code, I'll dig around and see what else I can find. I don't believe it is a setting that can be changed in wordpress, I think it has to be done somewhere in the custom code that generates the menu.

Comment: Ok I have edited the code in my original post with what appears to be another piece of code that references the menu. Does this lead to any clues?

Comment: Pleased to say that this is now resolved. I found a wordpress plugin called WP sorting which solves the alphabetical sorting issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WP3, your might be either the default WP theme Twenty Ten or is based on that theme, so look in Appearance/Menus to change the menu sort and levels. No code editing required.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question. The menu I am trying to sort is a submenu which consists of all the posts. They are not page or categories or anything like that so they aren't treated like menus in wordpress' admin.

Comment: I probably did becuase you haven't shown enough for anyone to really see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have edited the code in my original post with what appears to be another piece of code that references the menu. Does this lead to any clues?